# Count number of cycles in function MSP430

Tags: c, cpu, msp430

I have a matrix_multiply_test() function, using a timerA I need to count the number of cycles in this function. I need to do it with Profile Clock (I am using CCS). I am counting the number of cycles using a Profile Clock, but how can I print this amount in serial terminal?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QzYEvhnc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't put your code in a different website with an external link. Instead, provide a [mre] inside your question by editing it.